# Error installing homebrew on MacOS 10.14 Beta Mojave

Tags: homebrew

Im trying to install Homebrew on a fresh install of MacOS Mojave 10.14 beta.

Yet after running `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` (this is from https://brew.sh)

I am getting the error,

`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --install`

I have both the current command line tools from Xcode 9.4 and the beta command line tools for Xcode 10.0 beta.

Is there currently any workaround to allow me to install Homebrew?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the Command Line Tools for Xcode 10 do not install headers in /usr/include, but the install script checks there:

https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/bbf4a3a8b247c7dba159c3d557cc3853dd764171/install#L110

Thankfully, the code that tries to run `xcode-select --install` is bypassed if `STDIN` is not a TTY. Try adding a `0<&-` after the install command to close `STDIN` and skip this command. I just tried it and it worked for me.

As an aside, Homebrew does not officially support 10.14 yet, and the maintainers do not want you to file issues about any problems you find. (Pull requests seem welcome, though.) Unfortunately this means that the Homebrew issue tracker is not a place to discuss problems and solutions.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!